# WPF DataTemplate on ListView to visualize different kinds of user controls

Tags: wpf, listview, datatemplate

I have a ListView which I want to present different kinds of user controls, depending on which view model is set for the list view item.

In xaml:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:LabelledTextViewModel}">
                <controls:LabelledTextBox/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:FolderChooserViewModel}">
                <standardControls:FolderChooser/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
```

Now this works fine, but my `LabelledTextViewModel` can be editable or not editable. How do I say in XAML to check the property "IsEditable" on my viewmodel, and depending on its value show `LabelledTextBlockControl` or `LabelledTextBoxControl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `DataTrigger` in your `DataTemplate`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:LabelledTextViewModel}">
            <Grid>
                <controls:LabelledTextBlockControl x:Name="textBlock"/>
                <controls:LabelledTextBoxControl x:Name="textBox" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="textBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="textBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:FolderChooserViewModel}">
            <standardControls:FolderChooser/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your requirements, you either need to use the [`DataTemplateSelector` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) to make that selection for you, or you could try to name your `DataTemplate`s and set them using a `DataTrigger`:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewModels:LabelledTextViewModel}">
            <controls:LabelledTextBox/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AnotherDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewModels:FolderChooserViewModel}">
            <standardControls:FolderChooser/>
        </DataTemplate>            
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AnotherDataTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
</ListView>
```

This example assumes that you are setting the `DataTemplate`s to the `ItemTemplate` property... if not, you'll need to change that property to the relevant one.